# Video accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

our clients gave us a video that is mostly B-roll so they are saying they do not need to add captions to make is ADA compliant, but I'm not sure that is true. I know for images, if it's purely decorative you just leave your alt tag empty, but does the same rule apply to videos? Or do they still need to have captions describing what is going on in the video even though it's mainly decorative?

Comment: If the video does not contain substantive content (such as a B-roll would not), then I don't think captions are necessary for compliance, but for deaf users, I would consider at least some sort of indication that the content is not super-important, otherwise the UX might be frustrating for deaf users. This question is probably a better fit for [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll post it there!

Comment: [This question on UX SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/109663/17023)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/media-equiv-audio-desc.html)

> 1.2.3 Audio Description or Media Alternative (Prerecorded): An alternative for time-based media or audio description of the prerecorded video content is provided for synchronized media, except when the media is a media alternative for text and is clearly labeled as such. (Level A)

The video may be secondary but screenreader users or hard of hearing people for instance have the right to access the description of what happens in the video (i.e. audio-description). If nothing happens in the video, I would really wonder why people want to publish such video.